# How can I add a "no page break" constraint to a \vspace?

Tags: page-breaking, vspace

I'm using this command:

```
\newcommand{\opitem}[1]{\item[\planop{#1} \hspace{\leftmargin} \vspace{\smallskipamount}]}
```

in a document of mine. I want to tweak it so as ensure I won't get a page break before the rest of the text for this item. How would I best achieve that?

Comment: A \vspace in the middle of an \item argument? what should it do there?

Comment: why don't you remove both the spaces and just set the list parameters to have the space that you want?

Comment: you have not shown the relevant code but in most latex lists the argument of `\item[...]` is set in horizontal mode, so using a vertical skip is somewhat strange.

Comment: Can you provide a better MWE for your requirement, ie., from `\documentclass{}...\end{document}'...

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

There’s `\nopagebreak`. It works well when is placed before `\vspace`

```
This text is kept together with following equation on the same page
\nopagebreak\vspace{-.25em}
\begin{equation}
\ldots
\end{equation}
```

Another example. I use `tocloft` to tune table of contents. Without `\nopagebreak` inside

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\nopagebreak\vspace{.25em}}
```

I have

[image: without nopagebreak]

which looks silly, chapter is on this page but its sections are on the next one. But `\nopagebreak` refines the layout

[image: with nopagebreak]